# Why does fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') return different results depending on which database is in use?

Tags: sql-server

[fn_my_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097(SQL.90).aspx) "returns a list of the permissions effectively granted to the principal on a securable."

```
use master
select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') // 25 rows

use some_other_database
select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') // 25 rows

use a_third_database
select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') // 0 rows
```

Why would my SERVER level permissions depend on what database I was using?

Comment: Is a_third_database different from master and some_other_database with regard to 1) trustworthy bit and 2) owner sid ? Check these two columns in sys.databases

Comment: is_trustworthy_on is 0 for all three. owner_sids are all different.

Comment: Is suser_sname(owner_sid) of the third database returning NULL by any chance?

Comment: It's returning sa for master, NULL for some_other_database, and a valid domain user (other than me) for a_third_database.